# Single Line Horizontally scrolling text field using storyboards and Xcode 4.6.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, xcode-storyboard

Title says it all.  My goal is to have a text field whose text is changed to display a button push.  As the text reaches the end size of the text field, I want it to "chase" the last character entered and scroll to the right and only horizontally.  I also need to design this in storyboard.  I have found several explanations as to how to do this, most involving putting a UITextView inside a UIScrollView, all of them not using storyboards.

Is there a way to do this using storyboards only?

Comment: Did you get any solution to this question? I too am in a similar situation.

Comment: I have not.  That, and my XCode machine is down.

Comment: Apparently apple has not provided any proper solution yet.